# Rake task - specifying certain folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to specify certain folders in my take task using the `pattern` method.

At the minute my code looks like:

```
 RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
    t.pattern = "spec/models/*_spec.rb"
  end
```

So the code above will load all spec files in the `models` folder.

How could I change this to include the `controllers` folder, and `helpers` folder (for example).

So I want to create a `FileList` of all `*_spec.rb` files in the models, controllers and helpers spec folders (**AND** subfolders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the pattern is an array, so you can use the `<<` operator to append new patterns. For example

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern << "spec/models/*_spec.rb"
  t.pattern << "spec/controllers/*_spec.rb"
end
```

If you only want to run a specific list without the defaults just assign an array:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = ["spec/models/*_spec.rb", "spec/controllers/*_spec.rb"]
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to use FileList to do this?

Comment: You might need to clear the pattern before adding to it. So add `t.pattern = []` as the top line